# Text Binding to local property: Validation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

I am new to WPF and have a (in my opinion) strange problem:
I want to bind a local property (name: XmlText) to a TextBox.Text Property and validate the value with a Validation Rule like this:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Width="301" Margin="78,14,0,0" Name="tbXMLFile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="tbXMLFile_TextChanged">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                            Path=(Validation.Errors),
                                            Converter={StaticResource ErrorsToStringConverter}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="XmlText" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:RegexValidationRule Dateiendung="xml"></local:RegexValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Everytime my property XmlText gets a new value, the validation doesnt do anything, but if Im typing a text manually in my TextBox, it validates.

If I remove the TextChanged-Event or add the following code to the event, the validation wont work anymore:

```
XmlText = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
```

Can somebody explain why the programm acts like this?

Comment: Have you implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged for the object class you're setting as DataContext? Inside your property XmlText, you should raise the PropertyChanged event when the value changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is ValidationRules: they were not designed for doing what you're thinking!
Take a look to this article, to get more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx

(When you use the WPF data binding model, you can associate ValidationRules with your binding object. To create custom rules, make a subclass of this class and implement the Validate method. Optionally, use the built-in ExceptionValidationRule, which catches exceptions that are thrown during source updates, or the DataErrorValidationRule, which checks for errors raised by the IDataErrorInfo implementation of the source object.
The binding engine checks each ValidationRule that is associated with a binding every time it transfers an input value, which is the binding target property value, to the binding source property.)

If you implement the `System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo` interface in the class of the object bound, you will catch any validation (assigning the bound property and also from the UI).

They are just two methods, I show you an example with your properties:

```
public class TestObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _xmlText;

    public string XmlText
    {
        get
        {
            return _xmlText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _xmlText)
            {
                _xmlText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("XmlText");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "XmlText")
            {
                if (XmlText.Length > 5)
                    result = "Too much long!";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you binding validation should work perfectly:

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="XmlText"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
             Mode="TwoWay" />
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) The problem was, that i forgot to set the Binding-Mode = "TwoWay"...after that everything worked perfectly, even without the TextChanged-Event^^ So this can be marked as solved :)

Comment: Very good :)...is it working also with ValidationRule? Or with IDataErrorInfo?